# How to subtract time series element to get differance to the date before?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to build a dashboard chart in Mongo-Atlas.
The Table should should show the date on x-axis, the _id on y-axis.
The Values should be the count difference to the date before.

I have a collection with data points such as:

```
_id: "someName"
timestamp: 2019-09-05T06:24:24.689+00:00
count: 50

_id: "someName"
timestamp: 2019-09-04T06:24:24.689+00:00
count: 40

...
```

The goal is to get the difference of the count to the data point before. Having the same name.

```
_id: "someName"
timestamp: 2019-09-05T06:24:24.689+00:00
count: 50
difference: 10

_id: "someName"
timestamp: 2019-09-04T06:24:24.689+00:00
count: 40
difference: 17

...
```

That way I could make a table listing the differences

so far I created a aggregation pipeline

```
[
{$sort: {
  "timestamp": -1
}}, 
{$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  count: {
    $push: { count: "$count", timestamp: "$timestamp" }
  }
}}, 
{$project: {
  _id: "$_id",
  count: "$count",
  countBefore: { $slice: [ "$count", 1, { $size: "$count" } ] }
}}
]
```

I was hoping to substract count and countBefore such that i get an array with the datapoints an the difference...

So I tried to follow with:

```
{$project: {
  countDifference: {
    $map: {
      input: "$countBefore",
        as: "before",
        in: {
          $subtract: ["$$before.count", "$count.count"] 
/*"$count.count" seems to be the problem, since an integer works*/
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mongo Atlas only shows "An unknown error occurred"

I would be glad for some advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort:{
            "timestamp":1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$id",
            "counts":{
                $push:"$count"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "differences":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":"$counts",
                    "initialValue":{
                        "values":[],
                        "lastValue":0
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "values":{
                            $concatArrays:[
                                "$$value.values",
                                [
                                    {
                                        $subtract:["$$this","$$value.lastValue"]
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "lastValue":"$$this"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "id":"$_id",
            "plots":"$differences.values"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data Set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d724550ef5e6630fde5b71e"),
    "id" : "someName",
    "timestamp" : "2019-09-05T06:24:24.689+00:00",
    "count" : 50
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d724550ef5e6630fde5b71f"),
    "id" : "someName",
    "timestamp" : "2019-09-04T06:24:24.689+00:00",
    "count" : 40
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d724796ef5e6630fde5b720"),
    "id" : "someName",
    "timestamp" : "2019-09-06T06:24:24.689+00:00",
    "count" : 61
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d724796ef5e6630fde5b721"),
    "id" : "someName",
    "timestamp" : "2019-09-07T06:24:24.689+00:00",
    "count" : 72
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d724796ef5e6630fde5b722"),
    "id" : "someName",
    "timestamp" : "2019-09-08T06:24:24.689+00:00",
    "count" : 93
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d724796ef5e6630fde5b723"),
    "id" : "someName",
    "timestamp" : "2019-09-09T06:24:24.689+00:00",
    "count" : 100
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "id" : "someName", "plots" : [ 40, 10, 11, 11, 21, 7 ] }
```

**Explanation:** We are pushing `count` for the same `id` into `counts` array and then applying [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operation on it to prepare a set of new values in which current value would hold difference between the current and previous value of `counts` array. For the very first value, the previous value is taken as zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to do the trick an  the explanation helps me a lot for further applications.